# A function where $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \, dx=0$ but $f(x)$ is not odd.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find a function where $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \, dx=0$$ where $f(x)$ is
>   not odd.

This is easy to do using a piece-wise defined function. However is there an organic function out there that satisfies the property? By organic, I mean something that wasn't artificially created and convoluted to satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Azif00 That's odd bro.

Comment: Do you mean for all $a$?  or like $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos x dx$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If it were true for all $a$ then taking the derivative with respect to $a$ would show $f$ would have to be odd.

Comment: You need to clarify that $a$ is a fixed constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\cos$ is an even function, but $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos x dx =\sin x |_{-\pi}^{\pi}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

How about the *even* function $f(x):=x^2+c$ for suitable choice of $c$? For simplicity you can take $a=1$. Then setting the definite integral to zero yields an equation that $c$ must satisfy.

Answer (score 3):

Should be 
$$\int_{-a}^a \cos \left( \frac{\pi x}{a}\right) dx =0$$ for all $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of the cosine example, take $f(x)=g\left(|x|-\frac12 a\right)$ for odd $g$ with $g\left(\frac12a\right)\ne0$.

Comment: could simply take $g(x)=x$, for example; but if $g(x)\equiv0$ then $f(x)$ is odd

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Good point; I've added a condition to fix that.